# Alternative to mvn dependency:tree to see version of parent

Tags: maven, spring-boot

When you run `mvn dependency:tree` to some spring boot project you can see this:

```
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
```

All artifact got default version from parent pom when you dont override it. Is there some maven command to check info(version) of the project parent  ?

So when there is in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I would like to see something like this

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not showing the exact output you want, but it is quite similar.

```
mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.parent.groupId}: ${project.parent.artifactId}: ${project.parent.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q
```

Tested on Ubuntu, it shows something like this on my machine:
`org.springframework.boot: spring-boot-starter-parent: 1.5.9.RELEASE`

**-q**: quiet output, only show errors

Comment: thx a lot this sounds OK. I also found this maven command: mvn dependency:display-ancestors which also show parent of the project

Comment: Oh cool, I don’t have computer at hand. Does it show only one line?

Comment: yes it show something iike this: [INFO] Ancestor POMs: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.2.RELEASE <- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.2.RELEASE

so also parent of parent what I dont need but it is interesting :D

Comment: PS: mvn dependency:display-ancestors works with maven plugin version 3+ but your example works even with older version